# defining __DIR__ in PHP class

Tags: php, class, magic-constants

Is there a reason why this would cause a 500 error? Something to do with when it's executed and what's available, or am I using `__DIR__` incorrectly?

```
class MyClass
{

   public $filepath = __DIR__ . "/../downloads";

}
```

Comment: Are you trying to get `dirname(__DIR__)`?

Comment: I was hoping to just store `/path/to/file` as a string. That's how I've always used `__DIR__` in the past.

Comment: I assume your php version is >= 5.3?

Comment: @Layne `5.3.3`, correct

Comment: Well the first one makes sense that it isn't working but the second one is a question mark for me especially since it's working for me. Remember that `__DIR__` isn't a constant (first example).

Comment: Side-note: The first one should work as of PHP 5.6 - in fact, it's the [first listed new feature](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/migration56.new-features.php).

Comment: @Layne I think you're right, the second one works - must've had some other error. Still interested to know about the first. Must be a timing issue is my guess...

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol, shouldn't matter for `properties`. The added undefined variable `constants` at compile time in 5.6, but it's worked on `properties` for quite a while.

Comment: you can not assign an expression to the class property when declare. Only scalar value. So you can not concatenate there.